# Image URLs don't resolve in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, webpack

My problem :

Path generated for images are the same for images used in css or in a vue component.
Images are correctly loaded from CSS files, but are not found when declared in a vue component.

Version of webpack : 3.6.0

Here is the webpack configuration

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    publicPath: '../../',
    limit: 1000,
    name: utils.assetsPath('images/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
  }
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        name: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[ext]'),
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

sourceMap is enabled and publicPath is './'

All works correctly if files are deployed in server root directory, but it is deployed in a subdirectory, it doesn't.
Let's say I deploy my files in a 'dev' subdirectory.
Images in CSS files will be search in /dev/static/images/
Images in vue components will be searched in /static/images/, where they won't be found...

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong... Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: You probably need to 'require' them. `<img :src="getImage(image)">` and method `getImage(image) { return require(image) }`

Comment: I'm already using 'require' with `:src='require("./img/my-image.svg")'`. I don't see the point to use a function here.